# Creating a journey in Marketing cloud with Case Teams object as Entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are trying to create a Journey in Marketing cloud based on Case Teams as Entry source.
And we can see only Case and CaseComment and no CaseTeams.
And I didn't manage to find any information on whether we are missing some configuration setting or permissions to make it visible in Marketing cloud or is it not possible at all to use Case Teams as an Entry source.

Would really appreciate your help on that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce Support team:
A case team is a team of users that work together on a case.

Case team members can be added using ‘Case Team’ related list on a case record.
Hence a case team is not created/updated but is added/removed

So it complicates the data entry event logic as it works on Created and/or Updated

Hence case team as entry source is currently not available in Marketing Cloud. This feature can be possible in near future updates.